# junit testing error: ExceptionInInitializerError while creating object which have static instance

Tags: spring-boot, junit, initialization

I am trying to test one method, inside that I am creating an object of A class which has one instance variable as static. so while test case running it is throwing an exception `ExceptionInInitializationError`.

Not sure what's going wrong here.

```
A a = new A();//creating object inside method

public class A {
    private static final C c= BeanUtil.getBean(C.class);// giving exception at this line
}

@Service
public class C{
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after mocking ApplicationContext and setting that value to BeanUtils. it is working.

```
ApplicationContext mockedApplicationContext = Mockito.mock(ApplicationContext.class);

BeanUtil beanUtil = new BeanUtil();
beanUtil.setApplicationContext(mockedApplicationContext);

Mockito.when(mockedApplicationContext.getBean(Mockito.eq(C.class)))
                .thenReturn(c);
```